# Invertir los colores de una imagen que está codificada en base64

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una ruta de una imagen que está codificada en base64. Necesito coger esa ruta, enviarla al servidor con llamada ajax o lo que sea y con php invertir los colores de la imagen, para después obtener de nuevo la imagen codificada en base64 pero con los colores invertidos.

Estoy probando a hacer sobre la imagen

```
$imagenEn64 = $_POST['imagen'];

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagenEn64);

imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
```

pero no me funciona. NO hace nada. No me da ruta codificada en base64.

O si no se puede con php, invertir los colores de una imagen codificada en base 64 con javascript. Para esta segunda forma estoy intentando insertar la imagen dentro de un camvas y despues invertirlo, que si la muestro se ve invertida ok, pero al copiar la direccion de la iamgen sigue viendose sin invertir (es solo invertir negros y blancos ya que la imagen esta en blanco y negro).

Saludos.

Comment: Si esta es una pregunta de PHP, ¿por qué la etiquetaste JavaScript y jQuery?! Si vas a preguntar en 2 lenguajes diferentes, deberías hacer 2 preguntas independientes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En javascript puedes hacerlo usando un objeto `canvas` y aplicándole una "operación compuesta" (es una traducción libre) con el método `globalCompositeOperation`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// Muestra el contenido del canvas codificado en base64
function mostrarBase64() {
    var div = document.getElementById('base64Code');
    div.innerText = canvas.toDataURL();
}

// Crea la imagen inicial
var image = new Image();

// Cuando se acaba de cargar la imagen inicial la muestra en el canvas
image.addEventListener('load',
    function() {
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        // Mostramos la codificación de la imagen actual
        mostrarBase64();
    });

var button = document.getElementById('negativo');
button.addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Aplicamos el negativo de la imagen
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'difference';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // Mostramos la codificación de la imagen actual
        mostrarBase64();
    });

image.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,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';
```

```css
#base64Code{
  padding: 10px;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="negativo">Negativo</button>
<div id="base64Code"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias @AsierVillanueva . Me ha funcionado a la perfección. Te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
<?php
    function negativo($im) {
        if(function_exists('imagefilter')) {
            return imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
        }
        for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); ++$x) {
            for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); ++$y) {
                $index = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
                $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($index);
                $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255 - $rgb['red'], 255 - $rgb['green'], 255 - $rgb['blue']);
                imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $color);
            }
        }
        return(true);
    }

    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('kalle.jpg');
    if($im && negativo($im)) {
        echo 'Imagen convertida a colores negativos con éxtito.';
        imagejpeg($im, 'kalle.jpg', 100);
        imagedestroy($im);
    } else {
        echo 'La conversión a colores negativos falló.';
    }
?>
```

Sacado de http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagefilter.php y es que según parece, puede que en tu entorno no esté definida la función imagefilter, en cuyo caso, deberías tener un error en el log del servidor indicándolo.